# Question of connection between $0 < | x - c | < δ$ and $c - δ < x < c + δ$, and $x ≠ c$

Tags: limits

For a homework question of mine, it says:

$x$ is a solution of $0 < | x - c | < δ$ if and only if $c - δ < x < c + δ$ **and** $x ≠ c$.

I'm wondering if $x ≠ c$ creates the $ 0 < $ part, while $c - δ < x < c + δ$ creates the $| x - c | < δ$.

So, if $x = c$, does that mean $x$ cannot be a solution? Please help me with this dissection.

Comment: Perhaps you can answer this for yourself: if you plug $x=c$ into the inequality $0 < |x-c| < \delta$, which makes it $0 < |c-c| < \delta$, is it true?

Comment: Is this suppose to be a formal proof of the $\iff$ statement?

Comment: Treat it as two inequalities. (i) $0 < |x-c|$ which is equivalent to $x \neq c$ and (ii) $|x-c| < \delta$ which is equivalent to $x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta)$. If both are true then (i) is true and so $x \neq c$.

Comment: Use the following well known facts about the absolute value: if $b\gt 0$, then $|a|\leq b$ if and only if $-b\leq a\leq b$, and $|a|\geq b$ if and only if $a\geq b$ or $a\leq -b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things you need to know are the following general facts:

- $0\leq\lvert x\rvert$
- $\lvert x\rvert < b \iff -b<x<b$

Now, to prove the forward direction, suppose $x$ is a solution of $0<\lvert x-c\rvert<\delta$. We have that

\begin{align*}
\lvert x-c\rvert<\delta&\implies-\delta<x-c<\delta\\
&\implies c-\delta<x<c+\delta,
\end{align*}

which proves the first part. Now, assume, to the contrary, that $x=c$. Then $\lvert x-c\rvert=\lvert 0\rvert=0$. Since $0\not<0$, we have reached a contradiction, and it must be that $x\neq c$.

To prove the backwards direction, assume $c-\delta<x<c+\delta$ and $x\neq c$. We have

\begin{align*}
c-\delta<x<c+\delta&\implies-\delta<x-c<\delta\\
&\implies \lvert x-c\rvert<\delta.
\end{align*}

Clearly, $0\leq \lvert x-c\rvert$. Since $x\neq c$, we have $\lvert x-c\rvert\neq 0$. Hence, $0< \lvert x-c\rvert$. Putting this together gives us $0< \lvert x-c\rvert<\delta$.